# NHibernate, how to read NamedQuery result metadata?

Tags: nhibernate, sql, named-query

I have an sql-query define on my nhibernate mapping file, that call an stored procedure to select some records.

```
 <sql-query name="sp_MYSP">
     exec MYDBSP :param1, :param2, :param3
 </sql-query>
```

On code, I call the named query in this way:

```
  IQuery myQuery= Session.GetNamedQuery("sp_MYSP");
  myQuery.SetString("param1", p1);
  myQuery.SetString("param2", p2);
  myQuery.SetString("param3", p3);
```

to get results I use "List" method

```
   myQuery.List();
```

but in this way it return a list of objects without any meta information...like columname. I would read result like a datatable to get value of specific property...how can I do?

The selected records don't represents any entity of my domain modal, but only a collection of data use for a specific process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not mapping that query to an entity and expect a datatable, why use NHibernate at all?

You can still get a connection from NHibernate if you are actually using it for the rest of your data (session.Connection) and create a raw ADO.NET command from there.